# Scala Play + Slick: How to inject dependencies to Spec tests?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, play-framework-2.7

I'm using Scala Play 2.7.x (the project is available [here Play-Silhouette-Seed](https://github.com/bravegag/play-silhouette-seed/tree/slick-mysql)) and would like to test my daos. I have put together this simple one first to check what's the "new pattern" for testing play + slick + guice in 2.7.x:

```
package models.daos

import java.util.UUID
import org.specs2.mock._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import utils.AwaitUtil
import javax.inject.Inject
import models.generated.Tables.LoginInfoRow

class LoginInfoDaoSpec @Inject() (loginInfoDao: LoginInfoDao) extends Specification with Mockito with AwaitUtil {

  "Creating a new LoginInfo" should {
    "save it in the empty database" in {
      loginInfoDao.create(LoginInfoRow(0, UUID.randomUUID().toString, UUID.randomUUID().toString))
      loginInfoDao.findAll.size should beEqualTo(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, the guice dependency `LoginInfoDao` is not being provided to my test and then I get the error:

```
[play-silhouette-seed] $ testOnly models.daos.LoginInfoDaoSpec
[info] Done compiling.
[error] Can't find a suitable constructor with 0 or 1 parameter for class models.daos.LoginInfoDao
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 1 second, 966 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[error] Error: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 1, Passed 0
```

How do I get guice loading the needed modules for my test-cases?

A module is defined as:

```
class SilhouetteModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
  override def configure() {
    // ...
    bind[LoginInfoDao].to[LoginInfoDaoImpl]
    // ...
  }
}
```

and I have an `application.test.conf` available defined as:

```
include "application.conf"

slick.dbs {
  default {
    profile="slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
    db.driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytestdb?useUnicode=true&searchpath=public&serverTimezone=CET"
    db.user="dev"
    db.password="12345"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) (I'm contributor), that allows to setup isolated test for any JDBC base (as Slick is for MySQL) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another database for testing, H2 is the common choice.

```
class Module extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule {
...
}
```

With that name you need to let play know there is a Module to load, if you call it Module, it automatically know what to load and should work just fine (if you only need 1 module in testing)

If that doesn't work let me know

Comment: Thanks! but I already have a set of MySQL evolution scripts and they will not work in H2. Besides I already also have setup an `application.test.conf` pointing to a MySQL test database. The point is not what database to use, the point of the OP is how to get the Guice Inject system to provide me those Dao dependencies with minimal component overhead i.e. without loading the whole application components just for that.